# Im trying to find Mersenne prime numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>

using namespace std;

bool IsPrime( unsigned long long n );
unsigned long long pow2( unsigned n );
unsigned long long Mersenne( unsigned n);
unsigned long long Sqrt ( unsigned long long n );
bool LucasLehmer ( unsigned long long n );
double TIME ( void );

//------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
      for ( unsigned long long n = 1; n < 10; n++)
      {
           if ( IsPrime(n))
                cout <<" IsPrime "<< endl;
      }
      return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

bool IsPrime( unsigned long long n )
{
    if  (n<= 2 ||  n%2==0) 
        return n==2

    for ( unsigned long long  i=3; i<n; i+=2)
    {
         if (n%i==0)
             return false;
         else
             return true;
    }
};
//------------------------------------------------------------

unsigned long long pow2( unsigned n )
{
       unsigned long long ret= 1;
       return ret<< n;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

unsigned long long Mersenne( unsigned n)
{
      return  n-1;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

unsigned long long sqrt ( unsigned long long n )
{
       return sqrt(n);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

bool LucasLehmer ( unsigned long long n )
{
      if (n=2) 
          return true;

      unsigned long long s=4;
      const unsigned long long mp=Mersenne(n);
      for (unsigned long long i=3; i=n; i=++);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

unsigned long long Mersenne( unsigned n)
{
    return  n-1;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

unsigned long long sqrt ( unsigned long long n )
{
       return sqrt(n);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

bool LucasLehmer ( unsigned long long n )
{
       if (n=2) 
           return true;
       unsigned long long s=4;
       const unsigned long long mp=Mersenne(n);
       for (unsigned long long i=3; i=n; i=++);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------

double TIME ( void )
{
      struct timeb t;
      ftime(&t);
      return ( ( (1000.0 * t.time) + t.millitm ) );
}
```

I keep getting these error messages when i compile the code:

```
error: expected initializer before ‘if’
 if  (n<= 2 ||  n%2==0) return n==2)
error: ‘i’ does not name a type
  for ( unsigned long long  i=3; i<n; i+=2)
                                 ^
error: ‘i’ does not name a type
  for ( unsigned long long  i=3; i<n; i+=2)
                                      ^
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   for (unsigned long long i=3; i=n; i=++);
                                     ^
```

I just started taking this class and this is my first assignment any help would be greatly appreciated.

*I am using GNU GCC compiler

Comment: Downvotes? Come on, they just posted their first attempt!

Comment: IsPrime is missing the initial `{` (and the corresponding end one).

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: I didn't know that Stack Overflow was a place for "first attempts".

Answer (score 2):

You wrote in many places `if(n=2)` . You need  `if(n==2)`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the braces before isPrime definition:

```
bool IsPrime( unsigned long long n )
{
 if  ((n<= 2 ||  n%2==0) return n==2;)
    for ( unsigned long long  i=3; i<n; i+=2)
       {
         if (n%i==0)
           return false;
         else
           return true;
       };
 }
```

Comment: In function ‘bool IsPrime(long long unsigned int)’:
 error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
 if  (n<= 2 ||  n%2==0) return n==2);
                                   ^
 error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
In function ‘bool LucasLehmer(long long unsigned int)’:
 error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   for (unsigned long long i=3; i=n; i=++);
                                         ^                                                                 i made the change you suggested and I got this any suggestions....

Answer (score 1):

```
bool IsPrime( unsigned long long n )
{
    if  (n%2==0) 
        return false;
    for ( unsigned long long  i=3; i<n; i+=2)
       {
         if (n%i==0)
           return false;
       }
    return true;
}
```

Your `IsPrime` method has some bug. for `n = 1` it should be a prime according to your code. I've modified that part.

Answer (score 1):

`IsPrime` is missing the braces around the body.

The first line of `isPrime` ends with `)`, which should be `;`

You're using the assignment operator, `=`, for comparison.

This line is nonsense, and it's impossible to suggest a correction:

```
for (unsigned long long i=3; i=n; i=++);
```

If you wrote

```
for (unsigned long long i=3; i=n; i++);
```

it would be syntactically correct, but still meaningless - it either does nothing forever or not at all, depending on the value of `n`.